# Why does the GalleryView not refresh with new items?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, galleryview

I am going crazy trying to figure this out. I have tried everything I knew and nothing seem to be working. Any help in the right direction is much appreciated.

GalleryView does not refresh when in the same activity I press a button to start a ProgressDialog (in onPreExecute() method of AsyncTask) to update the String array that holds the items to be displayed in the GalleryView. In onPostExecute() of AsyncTask, I tried to call notifyDataSetChanged() on my adapter followed by setAdapter() on the GalleryView. onPostExecute(), I believe, works on the UI thread. Also, I tried calling notifyDataSetChanged() and setAdapter() in runOnUiThread() but that doesn't seem to work either. GalleryView does not refresh automatically with new items. It does, only when I scroll the view out of the screen and then back in again. The view updates with the new item only then.

Below is the code in parts:

On button click event, calling execute on UpdateGalleryview that extends AsyncTask

```
refresh.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            UpdateGalleryview updateGalleryview=new UpdateGalleryview();
            updateGalleryview.execute(GalleryView.this);
     }
});
```

Then in onPreExecute() method of UpdateGalleryview class, I am creating a ProgressDialog and updating the array that is sent to the Adapter of GalleryView.

```
private class UpdateGalleryview extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String>
{   

@Override
 protected void onPreExecute() 
 {
     final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(GalleryView.this, "Refresh", "Loading... please wait", true);

     new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

         //Updating the Uri[] that is sent to the Adapter for GalleryView
             File[] imagelist;
             File images = new File("/sdcard/thumbs/");
            imagelist = images.listFiles();

            mFiles = new String[imagelist.length];

            for(int i= 0 ; i< imagelist.length; i++){

                   mFiles[i] = imagelist[i].getAbsolutePath();

            }

            mUrls = new Uri[mFiles.length];

        for(int i=0; i < mFiles.length; i++){

            mUrls[i] = Uri.parse(mFiles[i]); 

        }

         dialog.dismiss();
    }

    }).start();

     Log.i( TAG, "onPreExecute()" );
     super.onPreExecute();

 }
```

Then, in onPostExecute() of AsyncTask, I am calling another thread that runs on UI

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute( String result ) 
 {
        runOnUiThread(updateAdapter); 
//          gaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//          ga.setAdapter(gaAdapter);
//          ga.invalidate();
//          ga.setSelection(midposition);

         super.onPostExecute(result);

 }
```

As you can see above, I even tried to update the Adapter (gaAdapter) with new items and the GalleryView (ga) within onPostExecute() itself. But that didn't work. So I created the new thread to do it, as below.

```
private Runnable updateAdapter = new Runnable() { 
        @Override 
        public void run() { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            gaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            ga.setAdapter(gaAdapter);
//                    ga.invalidate();
            ga.setSelection(midposition);
        } 
};
```

This is my Adapter code

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;
    int imageBackground;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        ctx = c;
        TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
        ta.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return imagelist.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(ctx);

        iv.setImageURI(mUrls[arg0]);

        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(180,144));
        iv.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);

        return iv;
    }

}
```

This is where I am at. GalleryView does not refresh automatically by doing the above.

Comment: If you post your code it might be easier to help you out.

Comment: I have edited my post with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be updating the array you use when you create the adapter the first time. You'll probably need to keep a reference to it in your class. Update that array, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() will do it.

Comment: Yeah, but the array he updates should be the one that was passed to that adapter, not a new array. I think that'll be the likely problem without seeing any code.

Comment: I am updating the same array and not creating a new one. I will edit my post with some code.

Comment: I've looked at the code you have posted. It still isn't clear that you are updating the array that is used by the Adapter. Post the code where you create the Gallery's Adapter.

Comment: Agree with @C0deAttack, we can't tell if you're actually updating the data in the adapter.

Comment: Edited my post with Adapter code and also see onPreExecute() again for the mUrls[] that hold the file path of new items that the GalleryView needs to be updated with

Comment: Your ImageAdapter class has "imagelist.count", yet the class does not have a class member named "imagelist". That class can't be compiling. It's obvious though that the array for the ImageAdapter is not referenced in your update code. Read my answer again, I'm certain it is the solution.

Comment: @C0deAttack Well, it turns out that there were a couple of things I wasn't doing right, including what you described. So I am going to partially accept your answer. I am still cleaning things up. Once I am done, I will post the solution.